# Eclipse: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: eclipse, fedora

I am using Eclipse 4.4.1 and i always encounter this error, i can not work with eclipse.

Is there any way to fix it?

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.ResourceTransfer.nativeToJava(ResourceTransfer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Clipboard.getContents(Clipboard.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Clipboard.getContents(Clipboard.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.PasteAction$1.run(PasteAction.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4590)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.PasteAction.updateSelection(PasteAction.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.selectionChanged(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionGroup.updateActionBars(EditActionGroup.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionGroup.fillActionBars(EditActionGroup.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionProvider.fillActionBars(EditActionProvider.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService$3.run(NavigatorActionService.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillActionBars(NavigatorActionService.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.selectionChanged(CommonNavigatorManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2171)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleSelect(CommonViewer.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1231)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
```

Session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: This is definitely finding something very large in the clipboard and running out of memory trying to look at it.

Comment: @greg-449 After computer restart, i think everything is clear, i will disable all applications and response as fast as i can.

Comment: I am looking at the source code of where your exception occurs, this code is definitely finding something in the clipboard (or there is a bug in the clipboard code)

Comment: @greg-449 Now, every time the Eclipse raise error, i copy some text(in any application), the eclipse will not raise error. So i think the problem come from my os(Fedora 20 Gnome with conflict app).

Comment: `launcher.XXMaxPermSize=2048m`: this is _WAAAY_ too big, it may be your problem. Set it around 3/400 megs maximum, you'll never need more than that (while keeping the heap as big as it is or bigger).

Comment: @guido I have tried with PermSize from 256m to 2048m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed this behavior after i installed `https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/`. Do you also have this extension installed? When I disable this extension (and restart gnome-shell) the exception in Eclipse is gone. Can you confirm this?

I have made a bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449902.

Comment: Exactly, as i commented: the issue may come from OS flatform :-)

Comment: I confirm I noticed the same problem in Eclipse CDT Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).
I disabled clipboard-indicator gnome extension and the problem was resolved.

Comment: I updated the gnome shell extension yesterday and it seems the issue is now resolved.

Comment: I can confirm this today. I was using Eclipse v1.8 (because of OMNeT++ limitations of the libraries that I'm using) with GNOME and with the Clipboard extension enabled. I disabled it, restarted and now it runs as it always should be.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how much memory you have on your computer, but you are very likely specifying overly large memory requirements.

Check this excellent answer:

- [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/)

Per your settings, I believe you would need 1GB of free memory to start, and could use much more than that if loading a large project.

If that does not help, then I also noticed that the exception is occurring in a method that would appear to be related to clipboard transfer. Is it possible you have a very large data set in your clipboard? That's just a guess and I don't know why Eclipse would want to transfer data from the clipboard on load.

Comment: I have 8GB, I have encountered this issue when eclipse start with default memory settings, then i try to increase the ram from 256 to 512 to 1024 and to 2048MB, but the problem still occur.

Comment: Then as I said, do you possibly have something large on your clipboard? (Try copying something small, like a piece of text.) Have you tried starting Eclipse immediately after restarting your computer?

Comment: Yes, but the very strange thing is i just encounter this issue after restarting my computer, if i wait for 15 minutes, the eclipse will work normally.

Comment: That is strange. You mentioned that you have tried starting with lower memory requirements. I have you applied the lower memory settings to both the Heap and PermGen ? i.e. -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  ? If that does not help, then I am not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Thanks @kaliatech for your effort, your suggestion i have tried before, i will try to reinstall java and eclipse.